Bound on the Wasserstein distance
Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be probability distributions on $( \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ with finite second moments. Let the symbol $C( \cdot, \cdot )$, with placeholders for two distributions, denote the set of all their couplings.
I am interested in bounding the following Wasserstein distance (squared)
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \int_{ \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 } | (x_1, x_2)-(y_1, y_2)|^2 d \lambda
$$
with the Wasserstein distance
$$
\inf_{ \mu \in C ( \mu_1, \mu_2 ) } \int_{ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} } | x - y|^2 d \mu.
$$
Here is what I have tried. For $\lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2)$ we have
$$
\int_{ \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 } | (x_1, x_2)^\top - (y_1, y_2)^\top |^2 d \lambda = \int_{ \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 } | x_1 - y_1 |^2 d \lambda + \int_{ \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 } | x_2 - y_2 |^2 d \lambda
\\
= \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_1 - y_1 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_1 + \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_2 - y_2 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_2, 
$$
where the projections $\pi^1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\pi^2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ provide, respectively, the first and second rows of the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1\\
x_2 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}
The question then becomes: Is it true that
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \left( \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_1 - y_1 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_1 \right) = \inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \left( \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_2 - y_2 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_2 \right) = \inf_{ \mu \in C ( \mu_1, \mu_2 ) } \int_{ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} } | x - y|^2 d \mu
$$
i.e., is it true that for $i=1, 2$ we have
$$\{ \lambda \circ \pi^{ -1 }_i : \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) \} = C ( \mu_1, \mu_2 )?$$
Finally, can we say that
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \left( \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_1 - y_1 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_1 + \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_2 - y_2 |^2 d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_2 \right)
$$
is equal to or is bounded with (a multiple of)
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \left( \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_1 - y_1 | d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_1 \right) + \inf_{ \lambda \in C(\mu^1 \otimes \mu^1, \mu^2 \otimes \mu^2) } \left( \int_{ \mathbb{ R }^2 } | x_2 - y_2 | d \lambda \circ \pi^{ - 1 }_2 \right) \\
= 2 \inf_{ \mu \in C ( \mu_1, \mu_2 ) } \int_{ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} } | x - y|^2 d \mu
$$

Have you tried to use Kantorovich duality? From every optimal coupling $\mu$ of the problem, you can construct the product coupling $\lambda$ for the product problem. Similarly, from a dual solution, it should be possible to construct a dual solution for the product problem. Do the function values coincide?

There is a more general result you can state and prove in order to bound the Wasserstein distance between product measures by the their individual distances, and I will do so for future reference.
Let $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ be a Polish metric space, take $p \in [1, +\infty]$ and let $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_N, \nu_1, \dots, \nu_N : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ be probability measures on $\mathcal{X}$. The $p$-Wasserstein distance is defined as
$$W_{p}(\mu, \nu) = \left( \inf_{\gamma \in C(\mu, \nu)} \mathbb{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma} \left[ d(x, y)^p \right]\right)^{1 / p} = \left( \inf_{\gamma \in C(\mu, \nu)} \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}} d(x, y)^{p} d\gamma(x, y)\right)^{1 / p}$$
We will show that
$$W_{p} \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n, \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n\right) \le \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}{W_{p}(\mu_n, \nu_n)^{p}}\right)^{1 / p}$$
To do so, we start by letting $\pi_n \in C(\mu_n, \nu_n)$ denote the optimal coupling between the corresponding measures for all $n \in \{ 1, \dots, N \}$. This means that
$$W_{p}(\mu_n, \nu_n)^p = \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}} d(x, y)^{p} d\pi_n(x, y)$$
The product measure $\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n}$, is a probability measure on $\mathcal{X}^N \times \mathcal{X}^N$ defined as
$$\left(\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n}\right) \left( \left( \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \times \left( \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N B_n \right) \right) = \prod_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n(A_n \times B_n)}$$
for all $A_1, \dots, A_N, B_1, \dots, B_N \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ where $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{X}$. We verify that $\left(\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}\pi_n \right) \in C \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\mu_n}, \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\nu_n} \right)$ by checking that
$$\left(\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \pi_n \right) \left( \left(  \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \times \mathcal{X}^{N} \right) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} \pi_n(A_n \times \mathcal{X}) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n(A_n) = \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n \left( \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N A_n \right) \\ \left(\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \pi_n \right) \left( \mathcal{X}^{N} \times \left(  \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N B_n \right) \ \right) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} \pi_n(\mathcal{X} \times B_n) = \prod_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n(B_n) = \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n \left( \mathop{\large \times}_{n=1}^N B_n \right) $$
Now consider the metric space $(\mathcal{X}^N, d_{N})$ where $d_N$ denotes the product metric for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{X}^N$
$$d_N(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = ||[d(x_1, y_1), \dots, d(x_N, y_N)]||_{p} = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}{d(x_n, y_n)^p}\right)^{1/p}$$
We can write the expectation under the product coupling as
$$\mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \sim \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n}} \left[ d_N(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})^p \right] = \int_{\mathcal{X}^N \times \mathcal{X}^N} d_N(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})^p d \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{n} \pi_n \right) \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \\ = \int_{\mathcal{X}^N \times \mathcal{X}^N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}{d(x_n, y_n)^{p}} d \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n}\right) \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}{\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}} d(x_n, y_n)^p d\pi_{n}(x_n, y_n)} \\  = \sum_{n=1}^{N}{W_{p}(\mu_n, \nu_n)^p}$$
where swapping the sum and integral is valid by Tonelli's theorem. Since $\bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \pi_n$ is a valid coupling we can relate its expectation to the infimum over couplings as
$$W_{p} \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n, \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n\right)^p = \inf_{\gamma \in C \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n, \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n \right)} \mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \sim \gamma} \left[ d_N(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})^p \right] \\ \le \mathbb{E}_{(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \sim \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N}{\pi_n}} \left[ d_N(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})^p \right] = \sum_{n=1}^{N}{W_{p}(\mu_n, \nu_n)^p}$$
Taking the $p$-th root, we can conclude that
$$W_{p} \left( \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \mu_n, \bigotimes_{n=1}^{N} \nu_n\right) \le \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}{W_{p}(\mu_n, \nu_n)^p} \right)^{1 / p}$$
as required. Note that when $\mu \triangleq \mu_1 = \dots = \mu_N$, $\nu \triangleq \nu_1 = \dots = \nu_N$ this simplifies to
$$W_{p}\left(\mu^{\otimes N}, \nu^{\otimes N}\right) \le N^{1 / p} {W_{p}(\mu, \nu)}$$
Your example is just a case of the above with $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$, $p=2$, $N=2$ and $d$ the standard $\ell^p$-metric.
